# How to scrape product details page on selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-rc

I am learning selenium . Right now my this code can scrape all product title from the font page of this url https://www.daraz.com.bd/consumer-electronics/?spm=a2a0e.pdp.breadcrumb.1.4d20110bzkC0bn but I want to click each product link of this page which will take me to product details page so that I can scrape information from product details page. here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

#argument for incognito Chrome
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" — incognito")

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://www.daraz.com.bd/consumer-electronics/?spm=a2a0e.pdp.breadcrumb.1.4d20110bzkC0bn")

# Wait 20 seconds for page to load
timeout = 20
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='c16H9d']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()



# find_elements_by_xpath returns an array of selenium objects.
titles_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='c16H9d']")


# use list comprehension to get the actual repo titles and not the selenium objects.
titles = [x.text for x in titles_element]
# print out all the titles.
print('titles:')
print(titles, '\n')
browser.quit()
```

Comment: I'd suggest looping, switching to a new window and scraping it.

Comment: Can you pleas give me example by writing code.I am a newbie who is learning selenium. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `BeautifulSoup` to make life easier.

I've modified your code slightly to illustrate how you could navigate across all the individual product links on a page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#argument for incognito Chrome
option = Options()
option.add_argument("--incognito")


browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

browser.get("https://www.daraz.com.bd/consumer-electronics/?spm=a2a0e.pdp.breadcrumb.1.4d20110bzkC0bn")

# Wait 20 seconds for page to load
timeout = 20
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='c16H9d']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

product_items = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"data-qa-locator": "product-item"})
for item in product_items:
    item_url = f"https:{item.find('a')['href']}"
    print(item_url)

    browser.get(item_url)

    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

    # Use the item_soup to find details about the item from its url.

browser.quit()
```

It is, in short, exactly what [arundeep chohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9901261/arundeep-chohan) mentioned in the comment section. You can choose to create a new instance of the `browser`, say `browser1 = webdriver.Chrome()` that can navigate all of the product URLs.

Also, I realized that the `incognito` mode is not working in your script.
You need to define `chrome_options` and pass it as an argument to the `webdriver.Chrome` method.

Comment: Cavin Dsouza thanks a looooot. You code was very easy to understand me. Your explanation helps me lot to understand how details page scraping work on selenium and bs4. I have two question. how to avoid ip block while scraping through BeautifulSoup and Selinium?   and how to loop multiple page like page 1, page2, page3?

Comment: You should add a time-delay in between page-loops, by introducing a `time.sleep(timeout)`, this ensures that you aren't making too many requests in a short period of time thereby reducing the chances of getting your IP blocked. You need to merely loop across the page links and scrape them. Check this script out: [link](https://github.com/CAVIND46016/Web-Comics-Scraping/blob/master/Channelate/channelate.py)

Answer (score 4):

Instead the click you mean, I suggest to get the `href` and open one by one.

You need this locator : `By.XPATH, "//div[@class='c16H9d']//a"`, and use `.visibility_of_all_elements_located` to wait all elements instead of `.visibility_of_element_located`.

After that, get the href with this method : `.get_attribute('href')`

And open a new window with the specific `href` already obtained.

```
browser.get("https://www.daraz.com.bd/consumer-electronics/?spm=a2a0e.pdp.breadcrumb.1.4d20110bzkC0bn")

# Wait 20 seconds for page to load
timeout = 20

elements = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='c16H9d']//a")))

for element in elements:
    #get href
    href = element.get_attribute('href')
    print(href)
    #open new window with specific href
    browser.execute_script("window.open('" +href +"');")
    # switch to new window
    browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])


    #......now you are on the new window, scrape here
    #example to scrape 'title' in the new window
    xx = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "pdp-mod-product-badge-title")))
    print(xx.text)


    #close the new window
    browser.close()
    #back to main window
    browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])

browser.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you frianH. I did lot of google to solve this problem but I didn't find any solution for selenium details page scraping. At last I find your code here and It worked. As a newbie of selenium python your explanation helps me lot to understand how it worked. Thanks a loooooooot again. Can you please tell me how to print the result on excel spreadsheet such as I want to print title.

Comment: and how to loop multiple page such as page1, page2, page3?

Comment: @FarhanAhmed Welcome, glad it worked. But for your request please open new thread.

Comment: @FarhanAhmed why unaccept? your question not about `BeautifulSoup`.